# Can't use if condition twice in Python terminal (syntax error)

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner, I apologize for the incorrect terms 
So I started that OpenClassroom course on Python and tried to copy this code:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> if a > 0: # Si a est positif
...    print("a est positif.")
... if a < 0: # a est négatif
...    print("a est négatif.")
```

but when I tried it:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> if a > 0:
...     print("a est positif.")
... if a < 0:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    if a < 0:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

after pressing the enter key after the second "if" condition it didn't let me write the instruction and only displayed the error.
Any thoughts?

Comment: After `if` you should use `elif` then finally `else`.

Comment: Or if you want it a separate `if` then press an extra enter after ending the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interactive interpreter, a compound statement isn't terminated until you enter an empty line. In this case, it means your second `if` is a misindented part of the first `if` statement.

In a regular script, there is no problem; the compound statement ends as soon as a line without the required indentation is discovered.